# IBM Bluemix: migrate mobile data service data

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I have a Push-Notification service set up that I need to migrate because IBM is closing the old service, with this service I have a Mobile Data service with many users. Then I created a new app and created the services: IBM Push Notifications, Cloudant NoSQL DB and Mobile Client Access. How can I bring the old users to the new app with the new push notification service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am truly sorry to say it's too late to migrate using Mobile Data or Push resources as the applications have been deprecated since December and finally taken down as of today in accordance with [the notice IBM put out towards the end of last year](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/12/15/important-mobile-services-announcement/). Additionally you should have received an email around March encouraging engagement with our support team to assist in migrating your application. Regretfully, due to the cessation of the old services, the data within those services is now inaccessible.

Without these resources to migrate I fear your best option would be to use the new backend services within your application and have users register to the new push service recreating your push subscribers and using the new Cloudant NoSQLDB platform to manage your data. Apologies for the inconvenience the deprecation has likely caused, please let us know if we can assist any in utilizing the new suite of mobile services.